# What is the practice for handling a complex resource pointer in C++ when allocating a new version of the resource?

Tags: c++, algorithm, design-patterns, resources

In most of my programming now a day I put everything in a smart pointer and *forget about it*. The resource is properly managed 99.9% of the time. It's really great and way better than a garbage collection mechanism.

However, once in a while, the resource being held by a smart pointer needs to be explicitly freed before we can reallocate a new instance of it. Something like this:

```
r = std::make_shared<my_resource>(with_this_id);

r->do_work();
...
r->do_more_work();
...
r->do_even_more_work();

r.reset();

r = std::make_shared<my_resource>(with_this_id);

...
```

If I miss the `r.reset()` call, the resource may either be using a large mount of memory or disk space and re-allocating without first resetting is likely to cause problems on smaller computers. Either that, or the resource is locked so it can't be reallocated until explicitly freed.

Is there a pattern/algorithm/something which handles such a case in a cleaner manner?

Comment: The problem with a "what is the practice for handling <X> in C++" type of a question is that, invariably, when you pose this question to three C++ developers you will get four different answers.

Comment: I don't get this.  `r = std::make_shared<my_resource>(with_this_id);` does `r->reset();`.  That's part of what makes it smart.  If manually calling release is the solution for you then there are big problems somewhere.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica On a reallocation, the `r->reset()` call happens when the variable gets assigned, which means the current instance of the resource is kept around until after the new instance was allocated. If the resource holds a lock against the resource, without the explicit reset, it fails. Another potential problem is when you allocate a really large buffer. It's going to be allocated twice until the assignment happens (although that will work unless you run out of memory).

Comment: Do you really want to call `r->reset()` (so`my_resource::reset`) or `r.reset()` (so `shared_ptr::reset`)?

Comment: @n314159 Ah, sorry, yes `r.reset()`, I made an update. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see basically two ways to approach this. The first is to wrap the reset-assign sequence into one function and never assign directly. I would probably do this like such

```cpp
template<typename T, typename ...Args>
void reset_and_assign(std::shared_ptr<T> &ptr, Args ... &&args) { //in-out parameter to avoid copy since you cannot rvo on a parameter
    ptr.reset();
    ptr.reset(new T(std::forward<Args> args...));
}
```

This is pretty easy and fast to do but it won't save you from accidentally calling the assignment directly and I don't see a way to do this if you keep using `shared_ptr`.

The other alternative is writing a wrapper around `shared_ptr` that just forwards most function calls and changes `reset` and assignment such that it will first deallocate and then create the new resource. This is a bit work to do and it is easy to get a bug into this (especially if you mess up some universal references if you try to save yourself some constructors). It will also be annoying to interact with other code that uses std smart pointers and will be a major refactoring process. But you cannot mess it up by accidentally calling an assignment (at least probably not).

Also note that the standard library does reset intentionally in this order such that we don't delete the old resource if the new allocation throws.

Comment: To avoid direct calls to the constructor we can make this function static and hide the plain constructor as private. This would be close to having a factory pattern.

Comment: It is more like strong typing, like when you create wrapper types for meters and seconds, even if they are just numbers such that you cannot add them by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Although it may sound bizarre, I believe this can be better expressed as move semantics. Here is why:

The new resource object you create is a replacement of the old one. Assume that the replacement is transparent to your users (i.e. they perceive the new resource object and the old one as the same). Therefore, it is as if you performed a imagined copy of the old object to obtain the new one, and then destroy the old one. This matches the intention of move semantics.

So `my_resource` should have a move constructor:

```cpp
my_resource(my_resource&& old) {
    old.reset();
    /* code to init the new resource object */
}

// replace
ptr = std::make_unique<my_resource>(std::move(*ptr));
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally you just put the `reset()` inside the destructor of the `my_resource` class.

If this isn't suitable for whatever reason, upon instantiation, you can put custom destructor function into the `std::shared_ptr` that calls the `reset()` and then deletes the resource.

If the `shared_ptr` doesn't reach the refcount 0 - are you sure you use it correctly? There is `std::weak_ptr` - a utility class for `shared_ptr` - made for the whole purpose of when you need both safety and timely deallocation.

Also, why use `make_shared` and instatiate new `my_resource` instead of simply using some init function of `my_resource` that will automatically call `reset()` if needed?

Comment: The `reset()` works. I do not have any _loop_ problem. It's more the specific type of resource which requires a current instance to be gone before it can be reallocated. (For example because the current instance has a lock which would prevent a new allocation until the lock is released.)

Comment: @AlexisWilke I misunderstood your question. It sounded like you need to call a specific function of the resourcs prior to destructor of the resource. It would be more clear if you wrote `r = {};` instead of `r.reset();` partially, because in another place you wrote `r->reset();`

Comment: Yeah, I fixed the second instance in the question (at least). _Unfortunately_, you can't edit and fix comments...